# matched cohort with 1:n pairs - correct stratified logistic model

Tags: r, survival, matching, case-control-study, clogit

*In this hypothetical example we have access to a database. In it cases are people with children and controls are those without kids. We want to measure the association between having children and Lung cancer.*

We match each case to `'n'` controls based on a given criteria. Shown below is the fantasy results obtained. In the example, n varies from 1:3 (first case matches with 2 controls, the second case matches with 1 control, etc).

We then wish to develop a stratified (by pair identifier variable) logistic model to predict lung cancer based on our matched case-controls. My question attains to the correct manner in which we are to deal with the 1:n pairs. Do we ...

**1: set the pair identifier number equal for each 1:n** (LHS below)

or

**2: duplicate each *case* such that it is repeated n times for each control** (RHS below)

The resultant (conditional) logistic regression model is then developed (in R) using somewhat of a code:

```
clogit(lung_cancer ~ case + strata(Pair_ID) + smoker, data)
```

So with respect to the `strata(Pair_ID)` command, which of the diagrams below is most relevant?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest the left hand one is the way to go.

Comment: great, I appreciate your suggestion and taking the time to attend to the question at hand, but is that a stab in the dark? Do you have previous experience with 1:n (should it be avoided?), or anything to support you suggestion?

Comment: You are trying to define the strata for the program. You already have the strata as they consist of the matched case(s) and control(s) so duplicating cases and defining strata as one per case is unnecessary. Consider what you would do if you had $j$ cases and $k$ controls per stratum in your original data-set, would you expand it to $j*k$ new strata?